# Odata V2 Java set EDM String MaxLength

Tags: java, string, odata, maxlength, olingo

We are using Apache org.apache.olingo odata jar in order to expose as odata Service in Java.

Facing one issue in EDM String MaxLength property. Not able to expose a string which is more than 255 characters in length.

We need to know where we can configure to extend the length of this "EDM.String" data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Facets](https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/api/edm/provider/Facets.html) class which has the method `setMaxLength(Integer maxLength)`.

[Facets examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.edm.provider.Facets)